# Como insertar registros en una tabla con varios id foraneos

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Tengo dos tablas creadas en mysql son:

**cat_taxes**
[image: cat_taxes]

**products**
[image: products]
Lo que requiero es poder registrar datos en la tabla productos y en la columna id_taxes poder agregar más de un id de la tabla cat_taxes

Comment: acepta mi edicion si puedes para poder ayudarte mejor :)

Comment: Lo ideal seria crear  _"una tabla de detalle"_ o mejor dicho una tabla de `1 a n`. En dicha tabla tendrías que guardar `product_id, tax_id` así podes relacionar a un producto multiples impuestos. Existen otras opciones, pero vas a tener que ser más específico en como quisieras guardarlos y luego obtener los datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problema

La propuesta de solucion que propones entra en directa violacion de la primera forma normal:

> Solo hay atributos de valor único.

O lo que es lo mismo, no meteras mas de un valor en una misma celda (columna), algunos crean el campo de tipo VARCHAR (texto), separan los diferentes valores con una coma o caracter separador y se meten en el problema de recuperar los diferentes valores con algun programa extra o codigo que no es necesario.

No lo hagas.

## Propuesta de solucion

Tu base de datos se ve asi:

[image: Modelo de base de datos antes de la propuesta]

Y aunque puedes asignar un mismo *cat_taxes* a uno o mas *products*, lo inverso no es posible.

Propongo lo siguiente:

[image: Modelo de base de datos despuesde la propuesta]

Este modelo te permite:

- Asignar un mismo *cat_taxes* a uno o mas *products*.
- Asignar un mismo *products* a uno o mas *cat_taxes*.

Con este modelo, evitas hacer redundantes los datos tanto de *cat_taxes* como de *products* y ademas puedes asignar tantos *cat_taxes* a los *products* que quieras.

## Codigo SQL de la propuesta de solucion

```sql
-- Crea un esquema (base de datos)
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `526503` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `526503` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 ;
USE `526503`;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `526503`.`cat_taxes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `526503`.`cat_taxes` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `526503`.`cat_taxes` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `rate` DECIMAL(5,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `526503`.`products`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `526503`.`products` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `526503`.`products` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `526503`.`cat_taxes_products`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `526503`.`cat_taxes_products` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `526503`.`cat_taxes_products` (
  `cat_taxes_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `products_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_taxes_id`, `products_id`),
  INDEX `fk_cat_taxes_products_cat_taxes_idx` (`cat_taxes_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_cat_taxes_products_products1_idx` (`products_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cat_taxes_products_cat_taxes`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cat_taxes_id`)
    REFERENCES `526503`.`cat_taxes` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cat_taxes_products_products1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`products_id`)
    REFERENCES `526503`.`products` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

USE `526503`;

DELIMITER $$

USE `526503`$$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `526503`.`cat_taxes_BEFORE_UPDATE` $$
USE `526503`$$
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`%`
TRIGGER `526503`.`cat_taxes_BEFORE_UPDATE`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `526503`.`cat_taxes`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    set new.updated_at = now();
END$$


USE `526503`$$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `526503`.`products_BEFORE_UPDATE` $$
USE `526503`$$
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`%`
TRIGGER `526503`.`products_BEFORE_UPDATE`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `526503`.`products`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    set new.updated_at = now();
END$$


DELIMITER ;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

### Datos de prueba

```sql
-- DATA, introducimos los datos que muestras en tu ejemplo.

INSERT INTO `526503`.`cat_taxes` (`name`, `rate`) VALUES ('IVA', '16');
INSERT INTO `526503`.`cat_taxes` (`name`, `rate`) VALUES ('IEPS', '8');
INSERT INTO `526503`.`cat_taxes` (`name`, `rate`) VALUES ('IEPS', '5');

INSERT INTO `526503`.`products` (`code`, `name`) VALUES ('01', 'Product new');

-- Si quieres asignar un cat_tax a un product, solo agrega los id de ambos en un registro en la tabla cat_taxes_products.
INSERT INTO `526503`.`cat_taxes_products` (`cat_taxes_id`, `products_id`) VALUES ('1', '1');
INSERT INTO `526503`.`cat_taxes_products` (`cat_taxes_id`, `products_id`) VALUES ('2', '1');
INSERT INTO `526503`.`cat_taxes_products` (`cat_taxes_id`, `products_id`) VALUES ('3', '1');
```

### SELECT muestra el mismo product con los tres cat_taxes asignados.

```sql
SELECT
    ctp.cat_taxes_id,
    ctp.products_id,
    p.code,
    p.name,
    ct.name,
    ct.rate
FROM cat_taxes_products AS ctp
JOIN products AS p ON p.id = ctp.products_id
JOIN cat_taxes AS ct ON ct.id = ctp.cat_taxes_id;
```

[image: muestra el mismo product con los tres cat_taxes asignados.]

Ojala esto te ayude.
Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el tiempo tomado en responder esta pregunta, me ayudo muchísimo a comprender.